# Render ember page on server using Django

Tags: python, django, ember.js

I have a Django application that has two parts:
1- Rest API using Django Rest Framework
2- Index.html - This is Ember app that calls the Rest API.

Both apps are hosted on Django server, and all is fine. 
Now I need a way to render Index.html page, which contains a lot of Ember.js code on the server using Django template render, or render_to_string and store the output as a static html that can be used later as a body of an email message, or just previewed on a browser.

So far, the template render, doesn't work! 
Do you have a better suggestion on how to do this? 
Note: I also want to pass additional route parameters to the server render like http:127.0.0.1:8001/#/books/1 ... http:127.0.0.1:8001/#/books/55 ...
So each one of these will be stored as its own html.